# Replace . for 0. in a txt file with a huge number of lines only in a certain number

Tags: perl, file, awk, sed, replace

I would like to replace the . in the second column with a 0. in the second column, in order to run a program. The original file has two columns and around 6 millions of lines and I don't have any idea how to do this.

```
rs4951859         .4251
rs142557973       .3874
rs141242758       .2732
rs79010578        .7447
```

---

I've tried

```
sed -i 's/./0./g'
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: sed -i 's/./0./g'  but it doesn't work! I am pretty new working with sed and awk!

Comment: Does your data have any numbers greater than one? We don't want to transform `1.0` into `10.0`

Answer (score 5):

The `.` has a special meaning in regular expression language used by sed. It means *an arbitrary character* which will effectively replace *any* character by `.0`.

Correct is to escape the dot in the search part, like this:

```
sed 's/\./0./'
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct as that'll replace any fullstops in any column, not just the second one

Comment: Well, that's fine with the example data because it contains only a single dot.

Comment: Thank  you very much it works perfectly! I was trying myself with another one:

Comment: sed 's/\./.0/g'  also works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to replace the . in the second column with a 0.

```
awk '{sub(/\./, 0, $2) }1' infile
```

- `sub(/\./, 0, $2)`  substitute, dot (`.`) with `0` in second field.
- `1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, print $0. To know how awk works try, awk '1' infile, which will print all records/lines, whereas awk '0' infile prints nothing. Any number other than zero is true, which triggers the default behavior.

Below one may be used, if dot(`.`) to be replaced with zero and dot (`0.`)

```
awk '{sub(/\./, "0&", $2) }1' infile
```

Comment: The `sub() + 1`  logic is very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how this is tagged `perl`, the equivalent Perl solution is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\./0./' YOURFILE
```

As with sed, `.` in a regex matches any character (except newline), so it needs to be escaped with a `\` if you want to match it literally.

Comment: If we're doing `perl` I'd probably build in a split in there, because then you can correctly select the column.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work with GNU awk, just add zero to the 2nd field:

```
awk '{print $1, $2 + 0}' file
```

Pipe the output into `column -t` to make it prettier.

If someone has time to benchmark, I'd be curious how much more slow this one runs.

Comment: It depends on the precision used. Check this: `awk '{$1+=0}1' <<< '.1234567'` --> output: `0.123457`